# Making a shell script but the script is not taking any input

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to make a shell script that works as an ordering system. I have started with the first steps but it does not take the input I am not sure of what I am doing wrong. I have attached an image of what end result should be. What is the next step I should take and what should I begin to research[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo "orderBeds"
read -p "Please Enter you choice (Quit/Order)" order
if [$order -e Order|order]
then
    echo "Please enter you name?"
elif [$order -e Quit|quit]
then 
     exit 
fi
done
```

Comment: *"Does not take the input"* is not a good description of the error. But `-e` is for testing the existence of files; to test the equality of two strings, use `==`.

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestion, but this has given me a new error on line 6 and 9 which is "command not found". what have I done wrong here?

Comment: `if [$order -e Order|order]` will attempt to execute a command named `[$order` with arguments `-e` and `Order` and pipe the output to a command named `order]`.  That is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Actually, the POSIX way is a single "=" sign; but "==" will work on the most recent shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the -e flag is for numerical equivalency.

Here is a corrected bash script to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "orderBeds"

read -p "Please enter your choice (Quit/Order) " order

if [ $order == "order" ] || [ $order == "Order" ]
 then
  read -p  "Please enter your name " name
  echo "$name placed an order"

elif [ $order == "quit"] || [ $order == "Quit" ]
 then
  exit
fi
```

Note the use of `==` instead of `-e` and the separation of the `or` clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've tested this out and the first function to order seems to work but the function to quit does not, I will do some additional testing to see what changes need to be made. The error is ( line 13: [: missing `]' )

Comment: @KevinMedjiako You also need a space before the `]`.

Comment: @KevinMedjiak Walter is correct. I updated the script (I had a typo). Bash cares about things like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start giving some general advice.

---

1) `[` ***is*** a command. That means you probably don't want to expand a variable just next to it without separating them with white spaces.

2) If you will check against more than one option, use the `case` construct. Apart from giving you the chance of a better structure, you'll be able to use globbing expressions as options to match against.

---

That said, let's rewrite your code:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

clear
echo "orderBeds"

read -p "Please Enter your choice (Quit/Order)" order

case "$order" in
    [Oo]rder)
        read -p "Please enter your name: " name
        echo "$name placed an order."
        break
    ;;
    [Qq]uit)
        exit
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: That's a nice one :)